# Flutter Drawer below AppBar

Tags: flutter, drawer, appbar, flutter-layout

I've implemented a `Drawer` in my `Flutter` app.

Closed `Drawer`:

[image]

Opened `Drawer`:

[image]

As you can see, the `Drawer` is on top of the `Appbar`. Before I started the app on `Flutter`, we had a native `Android` app with a `Drawer` that used to look like this:

Closed `Drawer`:

[image]

Opened `Drawer`:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildDrawer(context);
  }
}

Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  return new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.PROJECT_SELECTION, Icons.home, Colors.transparent),
        new Divider(height: 20.0),
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.TASK_LIST, Icons.home, Colors.transparent),
        new Divider(),
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.GUIDED_TASKS, Icons.home, Colors.transparent),
        new Divider(),
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.PHOTOS, Icons.home, Colors.transparent),
        new Divider(),
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.DOCUMENTS, Icons.home, Colors.transparent),
        new Divider(),
        _buildDrawerItem(context, EnumDrawerItem.LOG_OUT, Icons.home, const Color(0x85bf0202)),
        new Divider(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildDrawerItem(BuildContext context, EnumDrawerItem drawerItem, IconData iconData, Color color) {
  return  Container(
    color: color,
    child: new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(iconData),
          new Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: new Text(
              drawerItem.toString(),
              style: styleDrawerItem,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I know this is the standard `Material Design` style, but the client wants it as it was before.

Would it be possible to implemented it as in the 2 last screenshots? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrap your main `Scaffold` in another `Scaffold` and use the drawer of child `Scaffold` also make sure to set `automaticallyImplyLeading` to `false` so you don't get back icon in the `AppBar`

**UPDATE :**
i don't recommend this way because of this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20289)

```
return Scaffold(
      primary: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Parent Scaffold"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
      ),
    );
```

> Final Result :

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. One last question: would it be possible to keep the `Drawer` icon in the `Appbar`? As you can see, there is a `drawer` icon when it's closed, and a back arrow when it is opened. Thanks!

Comment: yes you can play with icon in the parent AppBar As you want using the Leading property and as i mentioned in my answer if you want the icon set automaticallyImplyLeading to true

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try. Thank you I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I've removed the `automaticallyImplyLeading` property in the `AppBar`. Now I get the back arrow when the `Drawer` is opened but no icon when the `Drawer` is closed :(

 can you please check the gif? http://recordit.co/IdRFflKuEH

Comment: try to provide a default icon using the leading property

Answer (score 12):

I use the key in scaffold and references in leading in scaffold principal how in the example

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Draw'),
      leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.dehaze),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen == false) {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            } else {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
            }
          })),
  body: Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    drawer: Drawer(),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Drawer'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    var appBarHeight = kToolbarHeight;  //this value comes from constants.dart and equals to 56.0
    return Scaffold(
      drawerScrimColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight+ appBarHeight + 1),//adding one pixel for appbar shadow
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Drawer(),//write your drawer code
      ),
      body: AnyBody(), //add your body
      bottomNavigationBar: AnyNavigationBar(), //add your navigation bar
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't trigger MediaQuery in your HomePage builder function, it will rebuild everything by every change on MediaQuery values and will reduce the performance. better to move your Container into a custom widget and use MediaQuery on it's build function

Answer (score 6):

**Simple and to the point:**

```
drawer: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 80, 0, 0),
    child: Drawer(),
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Even simpler with
'
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
'